# How to overwrite configurations in MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have project where I read configurations from json file in StartUp class:

```
services.Configure<ApplicationConfiguration>(
    Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationConfiguration"));
```

I would like to overwrite this with new values from data base.

```
public MyClass(IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration> applicationConfiguration,)
{
    applicationConfiguration = new DbApplicationConfiguration();
}
```

DbApplicationConfiguration class:

```
public class DbApplicationConfiguration : IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration>
{
    public ApplicationConfiguration Value
    {
        get
        {
            var configuration = new ApplicationConfiguration();
            configuration.Host = "myHost";
            // ...
            return configuration;
        }
    }
}
```

This is working, but only in MyClass.
I want to overwrite  configuration in container.
So that every time I inject `IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration>` I get new overwritten values.

I need to have possibility to update configuration on configuration page.
I would like to avoid changing interface in every class where IOption is injected.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Either write a custom `ConfigurationProvider` that will read and return the data from your DB. Or override the values explicitly in your `Startup.cs`. See https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#example-entity-framework-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most correct way for you to do that is to provide custom `ConfigurationExtension`. E.g.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddDatabaseValues();
```

You will have to provide the method yourself of course of reading stuff, but all the merging should be done by framework.

You need to implement `IConfigurationProvider` and add it to the `IConfigurationBuilder`. You can find a very simple explanation on how to do that [here](https://www.jeffogata.com/asp-net-5-configuration-custom-providers/).

Comment: The link ( https://www.jeffogata.com/asp-net-5-configuration-custom-providers/ ) is dead ;-)